# How to pass argument in a different way in Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, methods, arguments, overriding

I'm building an Android app in which I implement a supertype method of Activity called `onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked){
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.some_view);
        Animation anim = expand(view, true);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }
    else {
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.some_view);
        Animation anim = expand(view, false);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

And this method is then set to listen to a Switch in the onCreate method like this:

```
mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.my_switch);
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

The thing is now that  I want to implement this method not only for `some_view`, but also for a couple other views. Since I don't want to copy/paste this method a couple times and just change the some_view I need some way of passing the view. Since I'm overriding this method however, I cannot simply add an argument to the method. Since I set a listener to this method I can also not set the id to a global variable just before this method is invoked.

So my question is: how can I pass an id to this method so that I don't need to copy/paste the method to reuse it for several views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement your own `OnCheckedChangeListener` and one of the two options fitting your needs:

1. Use multiple instances of this listener. One for each pair of `<Switcher, LinearLayout>`.
2. Use one instance of this listener holding an array of `LinearLayouts` to animate all of them when switching the one `Switcher` instance.

This is the code, for both options.

```
public class MyOnCheckedChangeListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private final View[] mViews;

    public MyOnCheckedChangeListener(View... views) {
        mViews = views
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        for (View v : mViews) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v;
            if (isChecked) {
                Animation anim = expand(layout, true);
                layout.startAnimation(anim);
            } else {
                Animation anim = expand(layout, false);
                layout.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // inflate layout

    // option 1
    mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.my_switch);
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new MyOnCheckedChangeListener(findViewById(R.id.some_view)));
    myOtherSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.my_other_switch);
    myOtherSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new MyOnCheckedChangeListener(findViewById(R.id.some_other_view)));

    // option 2
    mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.my_switch);
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new MyOnCheckedChangeListener(new View[]{
                    findViewById(R.id.some_view),
                    findViewById(R.id.some_other_view)
            }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put all these ids in an integer array:

```
int ids[] = {R.id.view1, R.id.view2, . . ...};
```

set tag to `CompoundButton buttonView` on creation:

```
buttonView.setTag(ids[index]);
```

Then, inside method:

```
buttonView.getTag();
```

And, use it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) for the listener for each switch, rather than your Activity implementing `OnCheckedChangeListener` directly, each calling the following method (which is identical to your current listener, but shorter and takes a `viewId`:

```
private void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked, int viewId) {
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(viewId);
    Animation anim = expand(view, isChecked);
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Then on the switch:

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            super.onCheckedChanged(buttonView, isChecked, some_view_id);
        }
    })
```